# Check if a post is in specific category to show an icon

Tags: categories

I have multiple categories let's call them Group1 (imp1, imp2, imp3) and group2 (cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4).

My posts are in one from the first group of categories and in multiple categories from the second group.

I want to show a small icon in the corner of the post thumbnail if the post is from `imp1`, or show another icon if the post is from `imp2` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Add [`post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) to the post container div:

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <!-- post markup here -->
</div>
```

...which will give you, among other classes:

- `.category-{ID}`
- `.category-{slug}`

You can then target those classes via CSS to add category-specific icons.

Comment: Can you please give me more details?

Comment: What more (*WordPress-specific*) details do you need?

Comment: Can you show me how to do that with this code:
<?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, "thumb", true) ): ?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo ($thumb); ?><?php $values = get_post_custom_values("thumb"); echo $values[0]; ?>" width="156" height="132" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></a>

Comment: Sure. Just put that code where I have `<!-- post markup here -->`.

Comment: or I could use 
<?php if( in_category('SMS') ) { echo "This is something";} ?>